# Mifare classic 1k alghorithm encrypt

Tags: encryption

I'm new at this but I have a question about a mifare classic 1k that I use to eat in a necta vending machine.

I decrypted the keys easily with a software but when I saw the content, I don't understand anything... The card has 0.50€ but I cant recognise anything...

Normally in vending machines the money is in cents, in this case 050, in hex is 32.

[image: hex dump]

So I think the machine encrypts all data in this algorithm created by manufacturer. If I put another card from a friend with same money, the content of the data blocks are totally different in all lines...

It uses blocks 4 and 5. When I add some money, only the 3rd line changes (all line). All other lines remain unchanged.

Does anybody know how to decrypt this content?

Thanks